# How to set a value for a span using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How to set a value for a `<span>` tag using jQuery…

For example…

Below is my `<span>` tag:

```html
<span id="submittername"></span>
```

In my jQuery code:

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
    
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var invitee = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost/FormBuilder/index.php/reports/getInvitee/<?=$submitterid;?>",
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    var invitee_email=eval('(' + invitee + ')');
    var submitter_name=$.map(invitee_email.invites, function(j){ 
        return j.submitter;
    });         
    alert(submitter_name); // alerts correctly 
    $("#submittername").text(submitter_name); //but here it is not working  WHy so??????
});
```

Comment: You have misspelled the span's id (submitter instead of submittername).

Answer (score 856, accepted):

You can do:

```
$("#submittername").text("testing");
```

or

```
$("#submittername").html("testing <b>1 2 3</b>");
```

Comment: what is the difference between .text and .html ?

Comment: @Zaid `.text()` will escape any HTML characters so that it can be displayed as text. Use `.html()` if you're inserting HTML code that you want the browser to render. More info: http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2

Answer (score 21):

You are using `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {}` means here you are using `jQuery` instead of `$`. So to resolve your issue use following code.

```
jQuery("#submittername").text(submitter_name);
```

This will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 17):

You're looking for the wrong selector id:

```
 $("#submitter").text(submitter_name);
```

should be

```
 $("#submittername").text(submitter_name);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use this:

```
$("#submittername").html(submitter_name);
```

Answer (score 8):

Syntax:

`$(selector).text()` returns the text content.

`$(selector).text(content)` sets the text content.

`$(selector).text(function(index, curContent))` sets text content using a function.

Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jquery-change-the-text-of-a-span-element/

Answer (score 6):

The solution that work for me is the following:

```
$("#spanId").text("text to show");
```

Comment: For me it worked just like -> $('.className').text('some text') // span
$('.className').val('some text') //  input
$('.className').html('some text') //  div
$('.className').val('some text') //  input