# How can I change the text inside my <span> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a really simple question but it's something I have not done before. I have the following:

```
<td id="abc" style="width:15px;"><span></span></td>
```

I would like to put some text into the span.

How can I do this with jQuery. I know how to change things with the id of abc but not the code inside the span.

thanks,

Comment: Have a look at jQuery's [selector documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: @Felix. +100 . A link to the API worths more than a 'muted' line of sample code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set a value for a span using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491743/how-to-set-a-value-for-a-span-using-jquery)

Answer (score 223):

```
$('#abc span').text('baa baa black sheep');
$('#abc span').html('baa baa <strong>black sheep</strong>');
```

`text()` if just text content. `html()` if it contains, well, html content.

Comment: Note that having `<p>` inside of `<span>` is not valid with all doctypes.

Answer (score 59):

This will be used to change the Html content inside the span

```
 $('#abc span').html('goes inside the span');
```

if you want to change the text inside the span, you can use:

```
 $('#abc span').text('goes inside the span');
```

Answer (score 16):

```
$('#abc span').html('A new text for the span.');
```

Answer (score 13):

Try this

`$("#abc").html('<span class = "xyz"> SAMPLE TEXT</span>');`

Handle all the css relevant to that span within xyz

Answer (score -1):

Syntax:

- return the element's text content: `$(selector).text()`
- set the element's text content to `content`: `$(selector).text(content)`
- set the element's text content using a callback function: `$(selector).text(function(index, curContent))`

[JQuery - Change the text of a span element](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jquery-change-the-text-of-a-span-element/)

Comment: Please do not re-post copies of other answers (even if they are your own answers). Also, this answer could be improved formatting the code correctly (or at least commenting out non-code), and by using specific selectors as an example.

Answer (score -1):

$('#abc span').html("your new string");

Comment: This is just a variation of already existing answers