# Change text of span element when clicking on it using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="trashico">
    <img class="deskico" src="images/trashico.png"/>
    <p><span class="caption">Trash</span></p>
</div>
```

Here I want to use jQuery to change the text of the `span` when I click on the `div`. So what jQuery should I have to write?

Comment: If you want it in jQuery why tag as php?

Comment: You want to rename the name or the text?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: You need to write a click event handler which will change the contents of the span

Comment: Since you're working with jQuery can we see what you have tried so far?

Comment: ` $('#trashico').click(function() {
       $(this).find('span').text('Give Your Changed Text');
    });`

Comment: I want to rename text. For example here there is a **Trash**. Instead of trash i have to changed as i want.

Comment: [How to change span's text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222195/how-can-i-change-the-text-inside-my-span-with-jquery). [Bind an event handler click](https://api.jquery.com/click/).

Comment: So you won't be clicking the **div** you will be clicking the div's child element `span`?

Comment: can i changed its name as many times?

Comment: You don't have any name attributes set to change. You have innerHTML and class name.

Comment: [here](http://www.lamusamusic.com/) is my site.When you open it you will see Two folder. When you click on trash then you can rename it as you want. so check it then tell me what should i have to do?

Comment: @Nisarg You are aware that javascript is client-side so renaming something will only happen for the client editing it... (on page reload/refresh changes will revert to the original. _ before any client-side changes_) This won't update your website unless you have some server-side language editing and saving the changes...

Comment: I think making the field content-editable will be what OP wants. It can then be ajaxed to the server

Comment: No mention of ajax or sending data. Maybe the op should be more clear on what the end goal is/ wish to achieve.

Answer (score 5):

You can do like this

```
$('#trashico').click(function(){
   $(this).find('span').text('your text');
});
```

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted? This code works. An answer to a bad question should not be downvoted simply for existing.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the text of the `span` on the click event -

```
$('#trashico').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('span').text('new text');
})
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pqgb2x3v/)

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted? This code works. An answer to a bad question should not be downvoted simply for existing.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The same thing I am thinking also. :)

Comment: want to create functionality as we used in computer.Click on folder and press f2 key and we rename that folder.This functionality i have to create. so what should i have to do?

Comment: @Nisarg You want rename facility like `OS`s?

Comment: To make changes to web pages or directories will require a server-side language. Javascript is client-side.

Comment: You can use links to identify folders and rename them. Also need have proper permissions.

Comment: @Nisarg Javascript/jQuery is executed in the clients browser hence client-side. Languages like php are server-side, php commands are executed on the hosting server. I hope that helps you understand the difference.

Comment: he's talking about the same functionality as what f2 does when pressed on a OS. replication of this is possible on the web page itself!

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri That is not the answer. That will not the change the folder name on the drive.

Comment: @b0s3 that's exactly what I'm trying to explain but with the difference of client and server side languages.

Answer (score 3):

write the folowing click event

```
$('#trashico').click(function(){
   $('.caption').text('What ever new name you want');
})
```

**Update answer**

As for what you try to achieve is sort of the windows F2 functionality. Try the following logic. You would have to implement it using the base idea I've given.

```
$('#trashico').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active'); //Add a seperate class to identify on what is clicked
})

$(document).keyup(function(e){
   if(e.keycode == 113 && $('.active').length > 0){
      $('.caption').text('change name');
   }
})
```

The above code will add a class to the clicked icon on your page. Sort of selected folder on windows. Then there is a keyup event bound to the document where it'll listen to what keys are pressed. when it hits 113 ( is the keycode for F2 ) then the if condition would be true and you would be able to change the name.

This is the basic logic of the OS renaming function. You would have to go through this base to achieve your requirement.

Comment: why the down vote without correcting the error. This answer is not wrong! Please explain why the answer was downvoted!

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted? This code works. An answer to a bad question should not be downvoted simply for existing.

Comment: I think someone is down voting all answers for some silly reason. I will up on all correct answers.

Comment: Most of the downvotes are done before the edit. Revertred my downvote.

Comment: Maybe someone is down voting so the OP doesn't bother marking the answer giving them chance to submit another answer to get the mark/points.

Comment: Yes bt one should atleast try to explain why it's been downvoted.

Comment: Yes one should. Before the edit it has only the `click` event but not the way to change the text. Hope you can understand. :)

Comment: Yeah it was! So I edited the answer cus what I wrote was not answering the question entirely!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#trashico').click(function() {
  $('#trashico > p > span').text("changed text");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="trashico">
  <img class="deskico" src="images/trashico.png" />
  <p><span class="caption">Trash</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution. Here we are changing the text of `span` tag with class `caption`:

```
$("#trashico").click(function(){
   $(this).find(".caption").text('New Text') }
});
```