# How to change html inside a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the content of a span in my form 
HTML:

```
<form action="javascript:submit()" id="form" class="panel_frame">

    <label>Origin:</label>
    <div class="input-group" id="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="origin" name="origin" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button id="btn-default" class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
```

What I want change is che content of `<span class="input-group-btn">` with

```
<button id="btn-default" class="btn btn-default" type="button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

So what change is: the icon pushpin to remove and the action useCurrentPosition to clearPosition.

I' using jquery and despite I've read other answer about similar question on Stack like: [How can I change the text inside my <span> with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222195/how-can-i-change-the-text-inside-my-span-with-jquery) and [how to set a value for a span using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491743/how-to-set-a-value-for-a-span-using-jquery) I haven't solved the issue.

I tried:

```
$("#input-group span").html('
    <button id="btn-default" class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="br_bus.useCurrentPosition()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
');
```

,giving an id to the span and also modify the full div, but none solved my problem.
What am I missing?

Comment: `"#origin span"` searches for `span`s **inside** `#origin`, and there are no `span`s inside `#origin`.

Comment: I wrote wrong sorry while writing the question, input-group

Comment: Now code does work with `document.ready` (if script is before `form` in HTML) and having HTML code for replacing in single line: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3Lfnuuk/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to overcome the problem of changing the onclick attribute, which is bad practice, without storing a Global var, and using jQuery delegation (learn to use it, it's really good):

```
$(document).on('click','.btn', positionChange); // Give that button an id on his own and replace '.btn' with '#newId'

// Not using an anonymous function makes it easire to Debug
function positionChange(){
   var $btn = $(this), // Caching jQuery elements is good practice
       $span = $btn.find('span'), // Just caching
       pushpinApplied = $span.hasClass('glyphicon-pushpin'); // Check which icon is applied

   ( pushpinApplied ) ? useCurrentPosition() : clearPosition();

   $span.toggleClass( 'glyphicon-pushpin glyphicon-remove' );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than changing the function called in the `onclick` attribute I suggest having a flag in one function to define the logic it should follow.

For example:

```
function positionChange(this){
   var $this = $(this);
   if(!$this.data("currentpositionused")){
       //useCurrentPosition() code here
       $this.data("currentpositionused", true);
   }
   else {
       //clearPosition() code here
       $this.data("currentpositionused", false);
}
```

Then change your HTML to:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="positionChange(this)">
```

Comment: You should *not* use variables to hold UI state. This does not scale well.

Comment: And (especially having jQuery on the board) it will be better to forget about `onclick` attribute at all.

Comment: @Regent Although I 100% agree (jQuery use or not) I consider this outside the scope of the issue.

Comment: Well, we actually don't know what the issue with original code is at all :) As I have mentioned in question's comments, code does work inside `document.ready` with HTML-code to replace as single-line String. So this answer is first step of upgrading original code (fixing OP's problem as consequence/side-effect), and I have only mentioned second step of upgrading. And both our steps are outside the scrope of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("span.input-group-btn").html('<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="clearPosition()">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>');
```

Comment: This doesn't change nothing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change only the `onclick` attribute of the `button` inside the particular `span` you can use the following in your script.,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("span.input-group-btn button").attr("onclick","clearPosition()");
});
```

**EDIT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("span.input-group-btn button").attr("onclick","clearPosition()");
   $("span.input-group-btn button span").attr("class","Your_class");
});
```

And also learn about how to change/add/remove attribute values....

Comment: "You can use" *, using "have to" makes newbiews think this is the only alternative.

Comment: not only, I wanto to change also glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin

Answer (score 0):

Is it like This ?

[how to change onclick event with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452778/jquery-change-class-name)

```
$("#id").attr("onclick","new_function_name()");
```

[jquery change class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452778/jquery-change-class-name)

```
$("#td_id").attr('class', 'newClass');
```

If you want to add a class, use .addclass() instead, like this:

```
$("#td_id").addClass('newClass');
```