# Set the text in a span

Tags: jquery

I have this span

```
<a title="Prev" data-event="click" 
   data-handler="prev" class="ui-datepicker-prev   ui-corner-all">
     <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Prev</span>
</a>
```

I need to set the text of the span to be `<<` instead of its current text `Prev`.

I tried this below, but it didn't change the text as I'd expected. How can this be done?

```
 $(".ui-icon .ui-icon-circle-triangle-w").html('<<');
```

Comment: i guess it wont work because u need to pass ASCII code for that which is &laquo; try it i think its gonna work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set a value for a span using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491743/how-to-set-a-value-for-a-span-using-jquery)

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Use `.text()` instead, and change your selector:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-prev .ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w").text('<<');
```

**[-- VIEW DEMO --](http://jsfiddle.net/bwhfD/)**

Answer (score 13):

This is because you have wrong selector. According to your markup, `.ui-icon` and `.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w"` should point to the same `<span>` element. So you should use:

```
$(".ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w").html("<<");
```

or

```
$(".ui-datepicker-prev .ui-icon").html("<<");
```

or

```
$(".ui-datepicker-prev span").html("<<");
```

Comment: hmmm.. dont think this will work, because it will try to interpret the `<<` as html, no?

Comment: @musefan No. It **will** work. There is no need in `text()` method.

Comment: @VisioN This is only because in this instance it won't parse as HTML. I think if we're dealing with text content, `text` should be used. What if the user wanted `<prev>` displayed, then this would be interpreted as HTML

Comment: @Curt `<prev>` has a closing `>` bracket, hence browser will make a tag out of it. Otherwise, `<<` or `>>` will be interpreted it correctly.

Comment: @VisioN Why `html()` instead of `text()` though? I don't see a benefit, only a potential flaw. OP changes the content to `<prev>` at a later date, now they have to change the method being used to output the string. Why wasn't the correct method used in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

You need to fix your selector.  Although CSS syntax requires multiple classes to be space separated, selector syntax would require them to be directly concatenated, and dot prefixed:

```
$(".ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w").text(...);
```

or better:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-prev > span").text(...);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w').text('<<');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try it..
It will first look for anchor tag that contain span with class "ui-icon-circle-triangle-w", then it set the text of span to "<<".

```
$('a span.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w').text('<<');
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: Yeah sure....it will first look for anchor tag that contain span with class "ui-icon-circle-triangle-w", then it set the text of span to "<<". I hope you understand now...:)

Comment: Yes edit this in Answer which make your answer more help because just posting a code snippet is not right way to answer any question.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Give an ID to your span and then change the text of target span.

```
$("#StatusTitle").text("Info");
$("#StatusTitleIcon").removeClass("fa-exclamation").addClass("fa-info-circle"); 

<i id="StatusTitleIcon" class="fa fa-exclamation fa-fw"></i>
<span id="StatusTitle">Error</span>
```

Here "Error" text will become "Info" and their fontawesome icons will be changed as well.