# Ajax JQuery success function not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm not sure what has gone wrong, but for some reason the success function in Ajax isn't calling the function. I'm asking it to call after the PHP is completed.

For the PHP I have `$test = 'Hi'; echo json_encode($test);`

Here is my code for the main page:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["b2_in"])){
        header("Location: b2.php");
    }
?>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("form input:submit").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'b2_send.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            //beforeSend: function(){ $("#send").val('Sending...');},
            success: function(data) {
                TestFunction();
            },
            statusCode: {
                403: function(e) {
                    $("say").highlight();
                    $("#message").html(e.responseText);
                }
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
});

function TestFunction(){
    $("#message").val("");
}

</script>

<say>
    <form> 
        <input type="text" name="message" class="Message" id="message"/>
        <input type="submit" name="send" value='Say' id="send"/>
        <span id="message" style="font-weight:bold;color:red;"></span>
    </form>
</say>
```

Comment: `$("#message").val("");` will literally do nothing visible. So how do you know your function is not executing?

Comment: for `span`, you should use `$("#message").html("Your text");`

Comment: @Jivings When a user puts data into the #message field, I want their data to disappear after the input is sent into the database, the input is being sent into the database, but the field is not being reset.

Comment: does the page refresh after you click your submit-button? this could interrupt the execution of the javascript

Comment: @empiric The page does not refresh, I am trying to do as much as possible without a page refresh.

Comment: If the success isn't happening, the error is. Why don't you have an error handler? That should be step 1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491743/how-to-set-a-value-for-a-span-using-jquery

consider .text() or .html()

Comment: You can try and put a "console.log" before, after and in the success function and check the output e.g. with firebug and tell us whats going on (if everthing is executed)

Comment: Just realize the textbox and the span have the same id.  Try changing one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

span is a block element of DOM and hence to set data to it, you need to use `$(id).html(data);` and not `val()`

Also you should have different id for each elemnt in the dom, it always pick the first id that it gets in the dom, and in your case it is

`<input type="text" name="message" class="Message" id="message"/>` so it will change the value of this element

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("form input:submit").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'b2_send.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            //beforeSend: function(){ $("#send").val('Sending...');},
            success: function(data) {
                TestFunction();
            },
            statusCode: {
                403: function(e) {
                    $("say").highlight();
                    $("#message").html(e.responseText);
                }
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
});

function TestFunction(){
    $("#message").html("");
}

</script>
```

Comment: There is also a duplicate ID on the page, which will stop it working properly.