# Modification: Change from Input to Span and jquery /javascript is not finding and setting element value

Tags: jquery

I did have code that did work, but I needed to modify it

http://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/xbs5c41b

THEN I was told that I needed to change from input to label  (span)

NOW this code does not work even though I changed from

http://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/xbs5c41b/1/

```
.find("input")
```

to

```
.find("span")
```

Notice the code line that I commented out

```
 function setDateTimeOn(elm) {
        var formattedDate = GetCurrentDateTime(); //get formatted date
        $(elm) //clicked button
            .parent("td") // container td
            .next() // next td
            //.find("input") // find child input
            .find("span")
            .val(formattedDate); //set date
    }
```

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="width:5px;">
        <input type="button" id="GridView1__ctl2_AddButton0" name="GridView1:_ctl2:AddButton0" value="On" class="btn-blue" onclick="setDateTimeOn(this)">
    </td>
    <td style="width:150px;">
       <!-- <input id="GridView1__ctl2_txtStormTimeOn" type="text" name="GridView1:_ctl2:txtStormTimeOn" value="">-->
        <span id="GridView1__ctl2_lblStormTimeOn"></span> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

Can ".find() not work on span?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set a value for a span using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491743/how-to-set-a-value-for-a-span-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `find` method works.

The problem with your code is the `val` one, that doesn't, since it tries to find a `value` property on the element, and although the [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) has one, the [HTMLSpanElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSpanElement) doesn't.

You must change it to use the `text` method.

```
/* (...) */
.find("span")
.text(formattedDate); // set date
```

And here is [your fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/xbs5c41b/2/).

Comment: I did, there is always a 10 minute wait to accept BTW   thx !

Answer (score 0):

The span element is not neasted with your input, so you must use parent() to reach it's scope.
And plus, you don't use val with span, like div you must use text() or html() instead:

```
function setDateTimeOn(elm) {
    var formattedDate = GetCurrentDateTime(); //get formatted date
    $(elm) //clicked button
        .parent("td") // container td
        .next() // next td
        //.find("input") // find child input
         .parent().find("span")
        .html(formattedDate); //set date
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with   .parent().find("span")
        .html(formattedDate); //set date      It may work but I already tested the other code and that works fine for me   thx though